# Why did my phone vibrate when I went to a random website?

Tags: vibration

I was actually just searching something on google and out of nowhere a spam website opened and when it opened, my phone vibrated, why is this the case? Does this mean my phone's hacked?

Comment: It's likely to scare you into doing something stupid like clicking something to download malware, not hacking your phone//https://yandex.com/support/browser-mobile-android-phone/personal-settings/vibration.html

Comment: there are adds that makes you download their software making you think you got infected by virus, triggering red screens, making noise and/or vibrating your phone. Remember to always pick software from secure sources (like the play store), do not fall for those bad adds.